# SSD mount configuration for Varnish file storage

Tags: varnish, mount, solid-state-drive

I have Varnish 5.1.1 on Centos 6.5 and want to Use a fresh SSD for file storage, (my RAM 64GB get full quickly as I have a lot of objects to cache)

As said in Varnish Doc I have mounted a tmpfs partition for the working directory :

*"The shmlog usually is located in /var/lib/varnish and you can feel free to remove any data found in this directory if needed. Varnish suggests make sure this location is mounted on tmpfs by using /etc/fstab to make sure this gets mounted on server reboot / start."*

I have a dedicated 256 GB SSD drive for cache storage.
Do I have to mount it as tmpf with noatime like working dir ?
I did not find any suggestion on how to configure SSD for Varnish needs.

Answer (score 0):

No, you do not have to mount anything special if you're just going to use your SSD. tempfs is specific for a RAM drive only, and if you're not going to take advantage of the superior speed of RAM over SSD, then leaving /var/lib/varnish as is on the default install is good enough.

Comment: I have seen somewhere that it is better to mount ext4 or non-journaled partition to avoid too much writes on disk while reading because it would reduce SSD lifetime. https://superuser.com/questions/228657/which-linux-filesystem-works-best-with-ssd/  . So I don't think it is a good idea to not digg into this.

Answer (score 0):

`/var/lib/varnish` is used for logging, and Varnish logs *a lot* of data. Since it uses a circular buffer, size isn't an issue, however the I/O will wear your disks down.

TL;DR: always mount the work directory as tmpfs.